# How to update hashed password in .net core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm going to update my hashed password through **Http Put** action.

This is my **model**:

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public byte UserRole { get; set; }
```

and this is my **controller**:

```
    [HttpPut("{Id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutUser([FromRoute] int Id, [FromBody] TheUser user)
    {
        if (Id != user.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        CreatePasswordHash(user.Password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
        
        
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (_context.TheUser.Find(Id) == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return NoContent();
    }

    private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```

When I run the app I receive the following error:

[image: Error]

In fact, I'm going to reset users' password without knowing the previous password.

but the problem is two variables `passwordHash` and `passwordSalt` do not get the values.

Comment: The error you are actually getting is only related to Model validation. You have marked PasswordHash and PasswordSalt as [Required]. Remove that. You don't post these fields back from the view. Instead, you populate them in the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made these two properties `Required`, so you have to pass value to them.

You can remove `Required` attribute easily or pass **empty string** to those properties and **update** them using another action or method after being inserted into your **db**.